# Regex to get Jobid from string in shell script

Tags: regex, linux, shell

I want to get the Jobid from  string in shell script. I am able to get the jobid starts with "CY" using below code.

```
regex_jobid='CY[_0-9a-zA-Z]*'
temp="CY0PNI91354 Production AutoSys Job has failed. Call 249-3344. EC=111"

jobid="$(echo $temp | grep -oP "$regex_jobid")"

echo "jobid="$jobid
```

I need regex to get below jobID's that should start with any character.

```
MD0PN000609
ZCYNQNI93379
CY0PNI04806
CYM03922
ZCHI70490
ZCHI70511
PMI02649
PMI07530_sched_daily
IRZ02141
IWZ00306
IWI99990
USJ98000_sched
SD000206
WFI02272
```

Comment: should start with any character and should be alphanumeric

Comment: Are job IDs always the first word one a line?

Comment: No.. anywhere in string.. Example:Please hold the job MD000080_sched
In this case jobID is MD000080_sched

Comment: Then how to decide if it's a job id or just arbitrary text?

Comment: That we are not sure ..For suppose if the string is "CY0PNI94980 Production AutoSys Job has failed. Call 249-3344. EC=54.  RUN130990.", then jobid should be "CY0PNI94980 "

Answer (score 0):

Since your pattern may occur anywhere in the line you need to find all job ID like tokens first, then filter out the ones you don't want:

```
regex_jobid="(CY|IR|MD|PM|ZC)"
echo "$temp" \
|awk '{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) {if ($i ~ "^[A-Z][A-Z][_0-9a-zA-Z]*$") print$i}}' \
|egrep "^$regex_jobid"
```